# Delay a Shoutcast stream by 12 hours (Linux/bash)

Tags: shell, audio-recording, shoutcast

I am living on the other side of the world from my home (GMT+1 now, GMT+13 is home), and I miss my old terrestrial radio station. It has a Shoutcast stream, and I would like to simply delay it by 12 hours so that it is always available when I want to listen to it, in a way that would make its timezone be synchronised to my timezone.

I envision this as a script being run on my server host.

A naive approach would simply be to allocate enough ram in a ringbuffer to store the entire 12 hour delay, and pipe in the output from streamripper. But the stream is a 128kbps mp3, which would mean (128/8) * 60 * 60 = ~56MB per hour, or 675MB for the whole 12 hour buffer, which isn't really so practical. Plus, i might have to deal with my server host just killing the process after a certain timeout.

So, what are some strategies that might actually be practical?

Comment: Why isn't 675MB of RAM practical?  With the price of RAM nowadays, go spend $25 and get a gig... problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stream ripper would be the Easy way, and probably the Right way, but if you want to do it the Programmer way....

- Most development machines have quite a bit of RAM.  Are you SURE you can't spare 675 MB?
- Rather than store the output in a buffer can't you store it in a file or files(s), say an hour at a time?  (essentially, you would be writing your own stream ripper)
- Convert the stream to a lower bitrate, if you can tolerate the loss in quality

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just download it with a stream ripper like Ripshout or something?

Comment: I like to rip the stream so I can listen to shows whenever, not just exactly 12 hours later...

Comment: That's not my aim. I want to replicate the terrestrial nature of the original station, basically. The show that's on 9pm on Monday back home will also be on at 9pm on Monday where I am.

Comment: It probably is your best option.  Most shoutcast streams will boot you after 23 or so hours at best and caching to disk is infinitely better than ram.  A good ripper will break up the different shows into separate files.  When you're ready you could just play that show and delete the others.

Comment: The stream is old-school terrestrial radio piped into a web streamer, so there's no show metadata, so no show separation. The point is to take away my decision-making requirement. I just turn on 'the radio', and if it's good I leave it on. I can't believe it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

to answer my own question, here's a script that starts up as a cron job every 30 minutes. it dumps the incoming stream in 5-minute chunks (or set by FILE _ SECONDS ) to a particular directory. block borders are synchronised to the clock, and it doesn't start writing until the *end* of the current time chunk, so the running cronjobs can overlap without doubling up data or leaving gaps. files are named as (epoch time % number of seconds in 24 hours).str .

i haven't made a player yet, but the plan was to set the output directory to somewhere web-accessible, and write a script to be run locally that uses the same timestamp-calculating code as here to sequentially access (timestamp 12 hours ago).str, tack them back together again, and then set up as a shoutcast server locally. then i could just point my music player at http://localhost:port and get it.

*edit: New version with timeouts and better error condition checking, plus nice log file. this is currently running hitch-free on my (cheap) shared webhost, with no problems.*

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import urllib
import datetime
import os
import socket

# number of seconds for each file
FILE_SECONDS = 300

# run for 30 minutes
RUN_TIME = 60*30

# size in bytes of each read block
# 16384 = 1 second
BLOCK_SIZE = 16384

MAX_TIMEOUTS = 10

# where to save the files
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = "dir/"
# URL for original stream
URL = "http://url/path:port"

debug = True
log = None
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)

class DatestampedWriter:

    # output_path MUST have trailing '/'
    def __init__(self, output_path, run_seconds ):
        self.path = output_path
        self.file = None
        # needs to be -1 to avoid issue when 0 is a real timestamp
        self.curr_timestamp = -1
        self.running = False
        # don't start until the _end_ of the current time block
        # so calculate an initial timestamp as (now+FILE_SECONDS)
        self.initial_timestamp = self.CalcTimestamp( FILE_SECONDS )
        self.final_timestamp = self.CalcTimestamp( run_seconds )
        if debug:
            log = open(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY+"log_"+str(self.initial_timestamp)+".txt","w")
            log.write("initial timestamp "+str(self.initial_timestamp)+", final "+str(self.final_timestamp)+" (diff "+str(self.final_timestamp-self.initial_timestamp)+")\n")

        self.log = log

    def Shutdown(self):
        if self.file != None:
            self.file.close()

    # write out buf
    # returns True when we should stop
    def Write(self, buf):
        # check that we have the correct file open

        # get timestamp
        timestamp = self.CalcTimestamp()

        if not self.running :
            # should we start?
            if timestamp == self.initial_timestamp:
                if debug:
                    self.log.write( "starting running now\n" )
                    self.log.flush()
                self.running = True

        # should we open a new file?
        if self.running and timestamp != self.curr_timestamp:
            if debug:
                self.log.write( "new timestamp "+str(timestamp)+"\n" )
                self.log.flush()
            # close old file
            if ( self.file != None ):
                self.file.close()
            # time to stop?
            if ( self.curr_timestamp == self.final_timestamp ):
                if debug:
                    self.log.write( " -- time to stop\n" )
                    self.log.flush()
                self.running = False
                return True
            # open new file
            filename = self.path+str(timestamp)+".str"
            #if not os.path.exists(filename):
            self.file = open(filename, "w")
            self.curr_timestamp = int(timestamp)
            #else:
                # uh-oh
            #   if debug:
            #       self.log.write(" tried to open but failed, already there\n")
            #   self.running = False

        # now write bytes
        if self.running:
            #print("writing "+str(len(buf)))
            self.file.write( buf )

        return False

    def CalcTimestamp(self, seconds_offset=0):
        t = datetime.datetime.now()
        seconds = time.mktime(t.timetuple())+seconds_offset
        # FILE_SECONDS intervals, 24 hour days
        timestamp = seconds - ( seconds % FILE_SECONDS )
        timestamp = timestamp % 86400
        return int(timestamp)


writer = DatestampedWriter(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, RUN_TIME)

writer_finished = False

# while been running for < (RUN_TIME + 5 minutes)
now = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())
stop_time = now + RUN_TIME + 5*60
while not writer_finished and time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())<stop_time:

    now = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())

    # open the stream
    if debug:
        writer.log.write("opening stream... "+str(now)+"/"+str(stop_time)+"\n")
        writer.log.flush()
    try:
        u = urllib.urlopen(URL)
    except socket.timeout:
        if debug:
            writer.log.write("timed out, sleeping 60 seconds\n")
            writer.log.flush()
        time.sleep(60)
        continue
    except IOError:
        if debug:
            writer.log.write("IOError, sleeping 60 seconds\n")
            writer.log.flush()
        time.sleep(60)
        continue
        # read 1 block of input
    buf = u.read(BLOCK_SIZE)

    timeouts = 0
    while len(buf) > 0 and not writer_finished and now<stop_time and timeouts<MAX_TIMEOUTS:
        # write to disc
        writer_finished = writer.Write(buf)

        # read 1 block of input
        try:
            buf = u.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
        except socket.timeout:
            # catch exception but do nothing about it
            if debug:
                writer.log.write("read timed out ("+str(timeouts)+")\n")
                writer.log.flush()
            timeouts = timeouts+1

        now = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())
    # stream has closed,
    if debug:
        writer.log.write("read loop bailed out: timeouts "+str(timeouts)+", time "+str(now)+"\n")
        writer.log.flush()
    u.close();
    # sleep 1 second before trying to open the stream again
    time.sleep(1)

    now = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())

writer.Shutdown()
```